# How to handle nullPointer in Spring Data JPA projections

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Any thoughts if there's a way to have a custom method for handling null or any other exceptions happening during projection creation?

In the below JPQL query I'm trying to compose a custom object, but when there's no data under column updatedBy (it's null in database) - then it fails internally since cannot proceed with null object any further (getUpdatedBy -> getProfile -> getName).

```
@Query("select new john.home.com.demo.repository.projections.AgreementType(agreement.name, " +
        "agreement.type, " +
        "agreement.audit.createdBy.profile.name, " +
        "agreement.audit.updateDate, " +
        "agreement.audit.updatedBy.profile.name) from Agreement agreement")
List<AgreementType> findAgreementTypes();
```

Here are my entities:

Agreement:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "AGREEMENT")
public class Agreement {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "AGREEMENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "TYPE")
    private String type;

    @Embedded
    Audit audit;
```

Embeddable Audit

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Embeddable
public class Audit {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private SystemProcess createdBy;

    @Column(name = "CREATION_DATE")
    private LocalDate creationDate;

    @Column(name = "UPDATE_DATE")
    private LocalDate updateDate;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UPDATED_BY")
    private SystemProcess updatedBy;
```

SystemProcess:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_process")
public class SystemProcess {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROCESS_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "PROCESS_MSG_TXT")
    private String messageText;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private SystemProfile profile;
```

SystemProfile:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "sys_profile")
public class SystemProfile {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "PROFILE_NM")
    private String name;
}
```

Here's the JPQL query I've used, however it doesn't work due to unknown reason

```
@Query("select new dan.home.pl.demo.repository.projections.AgreementType(" +
            "agreement.name, " +
            "agreement.audit.createdBy.profile.name, " +
            "case when (agreement.audit.updatedBy is null) then 'Dummy Name' else agreement.audit.updatedBy.profile.name end" +
            ") from Agreement agreement")
    List<AgreementType> findAgreementTypes();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the case statement to achieve this
Check the documentation here
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

Something like

```
case when agreement.audit is not null then agreement.audit.updatedBy.profile.name end
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly that works but not in the way I expected. It is capable of changing records dependingon the case (smth like if a then 1 else 2), but what I'm trying to achieve is: if there's no object (meaning null) - place dummy string, otherwise retrieve string. Please have a look at the description, I've added query I used, maybe you've had such issue

Comment: @DanilTk Check examples in `Hibernate`'s documentation on [15.35. Searched CASE expressions](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-searched-case-expressions)

Comment: Yes even that is possible. The syntax is available in the documentation @MartinBG shared.
CASE {operand} WHEN {test_value} THEN {match_result} ELSE {miss_result} END